# Magento 2 bin/magento command prompting php version message

Tags: magento2, php, server-setup, localhost

I'm running Magento 2 on MAMP Pro local dev server (mac osx). I have site installed and running fine.

If I try to run following command in site root in terminal, `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` I get following message:

> Magento supports PHP 5.5.0 or later. Please read
>   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please upgrade your php version. or update your MAMP with latest version that support php 5.5.0or later

Answer (score 1):

OSX comes with a version of PHP installed, which can break things.

`php --ini` can tell you if you're running the OSX version of PHP, or the MAMP version of PHP.

You can also do `php --info` to double check the PHP version you're running.

MAMP comes with several versions of PHP, so you may also need to go into MAMP settings and change to a newer version of PHP.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145667/how-to-override-the-path-of-php-to-use-the-mamp-path

Comment: instructions via link resolved issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

add a PHP file named as "info.php" an at root directory with phpinfo()

open it through browser www.yourdomain.com/info.php

Here, search by $_ENV['PHPRC']  or PHPRC and get the value of it, in my case it was php:/opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php-cgi so my final command to clear cache would be 
/opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php bin/magento C:C